# The pipe 'ngrxPush' could not be found

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

I am new to NgRx and I have being learning for the past week.

So, I was trying to check the **Push Pipe** and **let directive**.

According to NgRx Documentation the installation of this guy would be using the following command:

```
yarn add github:ngrx/component-builds.git
```

My code is the following:

```
<ons-list-item expandable *ngFor="let user of users$ | ngrxPush">
 <!-- code here -->
</ons-list-item>
```

Well after that I tried to find the module that I need to import to have this pipe. To have the async pipe i just need to import the **CommonModule**.

Any Idea what should I import to have this working? Looks like the documentation is not too clear in this part.

Comment: Docs Updated: https://github.com/ngrx/platform/pull/2659/commits/b1cd2465fb2b27257511734fa9de864ee8cdc8b9

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to import the `ReactiveComponentModule`.

`import { ReactiveComponentModule } from '@ngrx/component';`

docs [here](https://ngrx.io/guide/component/let)

Comment: As of January 2023, it seems that the ReactiveComponentModule no longer exists in '@ngrx/component' `Module '"@ngrx/component"' has no exported member 'ReactiveComponentModule'.`,  use `import { PushModule } from '@ngrx/component'` instead.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE:**
import the PushModule from '@ngrx/component' as below:

```
import { PushModule } from '@ngrx/component'
```

In "@ngrx/component": "15.0.0" ReactiveComponentModule seems to have been removed.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue for my unit test.

> The pipe 'ngrxPush' could not be found!

The issue was persisting even though I've imported the correct module i.e. ReactiveComponentModule which contains the `ngrxPush` in spec.ts file.

In my case, the error got resolved when I fixed the mockStore's config(added the missing initialState attribute).

```
  providers: [
    provideMockStore(
      {
        initialState: {
          changePassword: false
        }
      })
  ]
```

I believe the stack trace provided by Angular for unit test is misleading.